# Jquery Layerslider - horizontal scroll issue

Tags: jquery

I'm using LayerSlider - The Parallax Effect Slider built in JQuery which is a lovely product but Im not having much luck getting the effect I need.

The CSS is causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear such that the screen can be scrolled to the right and that really doesn't look good.

Elements within the slider need positioned correctly and utilise the container_16 class to fit correctly.

You can see it in action here...

http://www.paramics-online.com/index4.php

Comment: this is because the div splashd getting bigger

Comment: @Julian just remove the **container_16** class from the div located in **splashd** div. It fill fix your issue.

Comment: Hi folks, removing the container_16 prevents the elements from lining up. The container 16 is needed to position the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting "overflow: hidden;" on the div with id="splashd" <strike>class "container_16"</strike> seems to do the trick.

Specifically add this to the css:

```
#splashd {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Arghh so easy! Thanks so much disperse!